# Creating a type definition for a property named "type" using JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to create a JSON schema for an existing JSON file that looks something like this:

```
{
  "variable": {
    "name": "age",
    "type": "integer"
  }
}
```

In the schema, I want to ensure the `type` property has the value `string` or `integer`:

```
{
  "variable": {
    "name": "string",
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["string", "integer"]
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it blows up with message: `ValidationError {is not any of [subschema 0]...`.

I've read that there are "no reserved words" in JSON schema, so I assume a type of type is valid, assuming I declare it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the specification](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor79), in the `Valid types`section for `type`:

> The value of this keyword MUST be either a string or an array. If it is an array, elements of the array MUST be strings and MUST be unique.
>   String values MUST be one of the seven primitive types defined by the core specification.

Later, in `Conditions for successful validation`:

> An instance matches successfully if its primitive type is one of the types defined by keyword. Recall: "number" includes "integer".

In your case:

```
{
  "variable": {
    "name": "string",
    "type": ["string", "integer"]  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer from jruizaranguren doesn't actually answer the question.

The problem is that given JSON (not JSON schema, JSON data) that has a field named "type", it's hard to write a JSON schema that doesn't choke.

Imagine that you have an existing JSON data feed (**data, not schema**) that contains:

```
"ids": [ { "type": "SSN", "value": "123-45-6789" },
         { "type": "pay", "value": "8675309" } ]
```

What I've found in trying to work through the same problem is that instead of putting

```
"properties": {
                    "type": {                 <======= validation chokes on this 
                        "type": "string"
}
```

you can put

```
"patternProperties": {
                    "^type$": {
                        "type": "string"
}
```

but I'm still working through how to mark it as a required field. It may not be possible.

I think, based on looking at the "schema" in the original question, that JSON schemas have evolved quite a lot since then - but this is still a problem. There may be a better solution.